# Forcing an NFC scan on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, tags, nfc

I was just wondering if it was possible to force a scan for NFC tags on Android and how to do it. I want to know if I can call something like `nfc.scan()` and have it return the tag info if there is any tag detected. I am kinda new to this Android thing and so far I have only seen it done with intents.

Comment: Maybe try read about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

No, Android does not allow you to trigger a scan for NFC tags/devices in range.

In fact, Android continuously polls<sup>1</sup> for tags while the screen is on (and unlocked) and there is no currently detected tag. Thus, you can register your app to be informed when a new tag is detected -> this is done through intents.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Most Android devices employ some energy saving mode that prevents the device from continuously polling for all kinds of tags. Instead, these devices detect tags by sending a short impulse and measuring detuning effects from inductive coupling.